# Android Navigation Drawer custom ListView not responding to Click

Tags: android, listview, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer

I'm using this tutorial to add sliding menu to my app:
http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/03/android-sliding-menu-navigation-drawer.html

I went completely as said in the tutorial but it doesn't respond to the click events,
(I put log.d in the onClickListener and see that it even not go inside the on clickListener)
(it shows the list icon and title perfectly(i don't get any error, exception,..) but i could't debug why it doesn't invoke the onClickListener..)
Thanks for your help in advance

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

/** slide menu **/
String[] menutitles;
TypedArray menuIcons;



/** nav drawer title **/
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private List<RowItem> rowItems;
private CustomAdapter adapter;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    /*******
     * 
     * for sliding menu
     * 
     * **************/

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    menutitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
    menuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.slider_list);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < menutitles.length; i++) {
        RowItem items = new RowItem(menutitles[i], menuIcons.getResourceId(
                i, -1));
        rowItems.add(items);
    }

    menuIcons.recycle();

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), rowItems);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideitemListener());

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name)      
{
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        updateDisplay(0);
    }

    // *******#for sliding menu*************

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.drawer_layout, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

}

class SlideitemListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        Log.d("in list listener", Integer.toString(position));
        updateDisplay(position);
    }

}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void updateDisplay(int position) {
    android.app.Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new FB_Fragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new GP_Fragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new TB_Fragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        setTitle(menutitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }

}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/***
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

and this is custom adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
List<RowItem> rowItem;

CustomAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> rowItem) {

    this.context = context;
    this.rowItem = rowItem;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView icon;
    TextView title;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_tem, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        RowItem row_pos = rowItem.get(position);
        // setting the image resource and title
        holder.icon.setImageResource(row_pos.getIcon());
        holder.title.setText(row_pos.getTitle());
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItem.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItem.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return rowItem.indexOf(getItem(position));
}
```

and this is list_tem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:background="#fff"
android:padding="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/bgc1"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="imgdesc" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Find your navigation layout container and set this after config drawerToggle:

```
navigationContainer.bringToFront();    
drawerLayout.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create fragment for each listitems , still if your are not able to resolve then you can download the code from this Link : http://download.tutorialsbuzz.com/subscribers/index_slidemenu.php

Comment: As ou see in the code, there is 3 fragments, the problem is the onClickListener isn't invoked to handle changing between these fragments